# Add a column to a nested table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, nested-table

I've this table

```
parlamentari
---------------
id|nome|cognome
```

Can i add in this table a nested column called telefoni?
I tried with

```
create table or replace type telefoni_nt as table of varchar2(10) after dnn;

alter table parlamentari add telefoni telefoni_nt  nested table telefoni store telefoni_tab;
```

without success.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want :

```
create table parlamentari( id integer, nome varchar2(20), cognome varchar2(20));

create or replace type telefoni_nt as table of varchar2(10);

alter table parlamentari 
        add (telefoni telefoni_nt)
nested table telefoni store as telefoni_tab;
```

and had a typo ***table*** at "*create **table** or replace type telefoni_nt*".

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b921a/1)

Comment: Excuse me, I have a little problem. Why when I execute together all these instructions the column wasn't created and when I execute these instructions one by one, was the column been created? What is the difference?

Comment: Ciao @keiichi, you can create the column  by issueing commands altogether as seen in the fiddle.